# How to call a shell script from python in multiprocess?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, subprocess

I want to run a shell script behind, which does a specific job, simultaneously I will wait for the user's input to end the job. How can I achieve this? Here is my example code:

```
from subprocess import call

cmd = "internals/applog.sh "
call([cmd])

raw_input("Press Y when you are done: ")
```

The above code first executes the call statement and only after the app log.sh ends then the following message comes.

Any help in this? how can I make it, when user enters y, the call statement to be aborted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pid = Popen(["internals/applog.sh",])

while True:
    answer = raw_input("Press Y when you are done: ")
    if answer == 'Y':
        pid.kill()
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

`call()` waits for the command to be completed, I think you'd want to use `Popen` instead:

```
from subprocess import Popen

Popen(["internals/applog.sh"])
```